# How to remove small polygons using Python

Tags: qgis, python, geopandas, filter, multi-polygon

I would like to perform in Python, the action done by the following QGIS command:

```
Processing Toolbox > Vector Geometry > Keep N Biggest Parts
```

It removes the smallest polygons from a multipolygons shapefile.

So far, I could just do in the following way (N=100):

```
#Read file
gdf = gpd.read_file('myfile.shp')
#explode and create area column
gdf_ex = gdf.explode()
gdf_ex['area'] = gdf_ex['geometry'].area
#filter biggest 100 areas
gdf_ex = gdf.sort_values('area', ascending=False)[:100]
#dissolve
gdf_simplified = gdf_ex.dissolve(by='CODE')
```

It works, but I suspect there might be a more direct way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will not consider each polygon/multipolygon on its own. So small singlepart polygons will be dropped if there are other multipolygons parts that are larger.

Try groupby:

```
import geopandas as gpd
n = 2 #Parts to keep if the geometry is a multipolygon
df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/multi.shp")
df["tempid"] = range(df.shape[0]) #Create a temporary id to group and dissolve by
df = df.explode(index_parts=True) #Explode so each polygon part become one row
df["singlepartarea"] = df.area #Calculate area 
df = df.sort_values(by="singlepartarea", ascending=False) #Sort from largest to smallest area
df2 = df.groupby("tempid").head(n) #For each tempid, keep the top n parts
df2 = df2.dissolve(by="tempid") #Dissolve back to multipolygons
df2.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/multi_n2.shp")
```

**multi** is the start layer, **multi_n2** is the result of the code above, **keep n biggest parts** is the result of QGIS tool:

With your code, the small FID=1 singlepart polygon will be dropped:
[image]